# In Excel, how to replace value from column 2 into column 1 if column 2 cell is not empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns in an Excel table. Column 1 is fully populated. Column 2 is populated with updated values for column 1. Not all cells in column 1 will be replaced. If the corresponding cell in column 2 is empty, then no change is needed. There are 6000 rows to change so I am looking for formula to do the work.  Here is an example of the table:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Data 1 | New Data 1 |
| Data 2 |  |
| Data 3 | New Data 3 |

Convert to this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| New Data 1 | New Data 1 |
| Data 2 |  |
| New Data 3 | New Data 3 |

Is there a way to do this with a formula or built in function?

Thanks!

Comment: A formula will not do this in place.  You can use a helper column with a formula then copy the values into the original.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose "Column 1" is in column C and "Column 2" is in column D.

> **METHOD 1:** Let's say you have "Data 1" in cell "D2" and "New Data 1" in cell "C2". Then you can use the funtion "IF" and the function "ISBLANK" to get a new column with the results (and then you scroll down the function):

=IF(ISBLANK(D2);C2;D2)

> **METHOD 2:** If instead you want to replace the data on the same column (C), you have to run a loop in VBA like this one (please replace "SheetName" with your sheet name):

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange()
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("SheetName").Range("C1:C10000"))
    Worksheets("SheetName").Select
    For i = 1 To x:
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "D").Value) Then
            Cells(i, "C").Value = Cells(i, "D").Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Edoardo. Method 1 did not work and I am not familiar with VBA.  Here is my updated code:
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("2021").Range("C1:C6000"))
    Worksheets("2021").Select
    For i = 1 To x:
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "C").Value) Then
        Cells(i, "B").Value = Cells(i, "C").Value
        End If
    End Sub

I am getting a Compile Error: For without Next

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: Hi Jim. I updated Method 2

Comment: As for method 1, it seems very strange that it does not work for you. Have you set English as the Excel language or do you have a different language? In case you are using a different language, you need to look for the correct "IF" and "ISBLANK" functions in your language.

Comment: Also, it can be that in your Excel version you must use "," instead of ";". If you write in a cell "=IF(" it would appear the right punctuation to use.